# How to return a variable number of values?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have to write a function which looks like the following: `def funci(x1, ..., xki) -> y1,...,ymi`, where all `x`'s and `y`'s have type `TypeClass`.
Using `typing` module, I could declare the function as: `f(*args: TypeClass)`, but how to define the type of the variable-length returned values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `typing` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple),

> To specify a variable-length tuple of homogeneous type, use literal ellipsis, e.g. Tuple[int, ...].

In your case, the return type should be `Tuple[TypeClass, ...]`.